# Find the second position of a text in python

Tags: python, find

In this example:

```py
txt = "Hello, welcome to my world."
x = txt.find("e", 5, 10)
print(x)
```

X value is 8. find is working between caracter 5 and 10.

I have a string variable, got from a PDF document as below:

```
"CIDADE  DE SÃO PAULO  
SECRETARIA MUNICIPAL DA SAÚDE  
DIVISÃO TÉCNICA DE SUPRIMENTOS  
SETOR DE ATAS DE REGISTRO DE PREÇOS  
Rua General Jardim, 36 – 3° andar – Vila Buarque – CEP 01223 -010 
E X T R A T O  
 
ATA DE REGISTRO DE PREÇO nº 844/2022 -SMS.G (25%)  
PROCESSO ADMINISTRATIVO nº  6018.2022/0074945 -9 
PREGÃO ELETRÔNICO Nº 918/2022/SMS.G  
ORGÃO GESTOR: SECRETARIA MUNICIPAL DA SAÚDE  
DETENTORA:  PRINCE MED DISTRIBUIDORA DE PRODUTOS 
HOSPITALARES LTDA  
CNPJ:  35.848.045/0001 -03 
OBJETO : FORMULA LÁCTEA INFAN TIL 
VIGÊNC IA: 05/12 /2022 A 05/12 /2023 
 
 
Item 02 - FÓRMULA LACTEA, INFANTIL, PÓ, LACTENTES 0 A 6 MESES 
DE VIDA, 800 GR  
R$ 29,55/LATA  
MARCA: NAN CONFOR 1  
FABRICANTE: NESTLÉ  
EMBALAGEM/APRESENTAÇÃO: CX C/ 6 LATAS C/ 800 G  
REGISTRO NO M.S:  400761911  
PROCEDEN CIA: NACIONAL  
Código Supri: 11.260.011.002.0115 -3 
 
Item 04 - FORMULA INFANTIL, SEGUIMENTO, EM PÓ, PARA LACTENTES 
A PARTIR DO 6º MES DE VIDA 800 G  
R$ 28,15/LATA  
MARCA: NAN CONFOR 2  
FABRICANTE: NESTLÉ  
EMBALAGEM/APRESENTAÇÃO: CX C/ 6 LATAS C/ 800 G  
REGISTRO NO M.S:  400761951  
PROCEDENCIA: NACIONAL  
Código Supri: 11.260.011.002.0063 -7 "
```

I need to recovery the description after "Item 0", example:

```
"FÓRMULA LACTEA, INFANTIL, PÓ, LACTENTES 0 A 6 MESES"
```

When I run the code below, I got the answer:

```
print(text.find("Item 0"))
position: 573
```

Now I need to catch the second Item, só a should seek after character 573:

```
print(text.find("Item 0"), 574)
Python: 573 574
```

Considering the example listed in first part of my question, which the "e" letter should be find between positions 5 and 10, in my problem, Python is answering with first position of "Item 0" what has been found and 574 value, which should be where it would start to find.

I apreciate your support.
Kind regards.

got the second position of text "Item 0".

Comment: Do you mean `print(text.find("Item 0", 574))` instead of `print(text.find("Item 0"), 574)` ?

Comment: You seem to already know that you can specify the start index for the search, so it's unclear to me what the problem is.